# Errno 13 when open, even with permissions enabled

Tags: python

I am learning python 3 and was following along a tutorial on how to use the builtin open() function.
I am using python 3.8 on Windows 10.

The problem I encounter when running the code below is that it acts as though I don't have permissions to that file. I've checked and made sure I have have full permissions in the folder (which is what appears to be the problem in many cases of Errno 13).

My python script:

```
file = open("sample.txt","w")

file.write('Hello World')
file.write('This is written using Python')

file.close()
```

The error I get in the console (full file-path omitted):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\....movement.py", line 3, in <module>
    file = open("sample.txt","w")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'sample.txt'
```

Some additional details:

- The text file is blank (I intended to write to it)
- I already made sure the folder containing the script and the text file is not read-only

Any help would be appreciated :)

**Update 1**
Tried:

- text file and containing folder are closed
- creating text file using command line

**Update 2**
Looks like my current directory is wrong (C:\Program Files\Notepad++)
Is there a way to set the path in the python script itself, or should I delve into the Notepad++ settings?

Comment: Have you tried launching command prompt as an administrator before you execute your script?

Comment: @PrateekDewan - That's a risky thing to do.

Comment: Can you create this file from the command line or with notepad? Its possible its open in some other program.

Comment: Are you running this inside an IDE or Windowed environment? You may be in a different directory than you think. `print(os.getcwd())` would confirm.

Comment: If the working directory is the `C:` drive, for example, you can't just create a file there.

Comment: I tried the `print(os.getcwd())` but it returns: `NameError: name 'os' is not defined`

Comment: I think you are <code> r'C:\Program Files\ <\code>, if so please change your directory, in there you need admin permission.

Comment: @Geek-number-Avogadro if `os` isn't defined you need to import it. Put `import os` at the top of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here's a fix:

```
import os 
import pathlib

print(os.getcwd())

#Get the path to this script
path = (pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute())

#Change the path to the correct one
os.chdir(path)

print(os.getcwd())
```

Adding the above code to the beginning of the script changes the path to the location of the script file. This solves the permissions issue and allows python to use open() properly.

Thanks to everyone who helped me figure this out!